# Jquery find element returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success m-t-xs invite_accept">Accept</button>
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger m-t-xs invite_decline">Decline</button>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $notification['team_id']?>" class="team_id">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $notification['invite_id']?>" class="invite_id">
```

Now when the accept button is pressed i have the following Javascript:

```
$('.notifications').on('click', '.invite_accept', function(){
    accept_invite($(this).next('.team_id').val(), $(this).next('.invite_id').val());
});
```

However this returns `undefined`.

```
   function accept_invite(team_id, invite_id){
   alert(''+team_id+' '+invite_id);
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? i have been debugging this for an hour now using both `next` and `find`

Comment: Where is your accept_invite function?

Comment: [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) only get the immediately following sibling

Comment: @gnack added my accept function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your context `.team_id` and `.invite_id` are not the next(immediate) siblings of the current element. So  you should use `.siblings()` to achieve what you want.

Try,

```
$('.notifications').on('click', '.invite_accept', function(){
    accept_invite($(this).siblings('.team_id').val(), $(this).siblings('.invite_id').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(this) in click function refers to the button and next() will only return adjacent control. Assuming $(".notifications") is a container so you can find your control in that container like $(".notifications").find(".team_id").val().